# How to convert DataFrame to Dataset in Apache Spark in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I can convert DataFrame to Dataset in Scala very easy:

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Long)
val df = ctx.read.json("/tmp/persons.json")
val ds = df.as[Person]
ds.printSchema
```

but in Java version I don't know how to convert Dataframe to Dataset? Any Idea?

my effort is:

```
DataFrame df = ctx.read().json(logFile);
Encoder<Person> encoder = new Encoder<>();
Dataset<Person> ds = new Dataset<Person>(ctx,df.logicalPlan(),encoder);
ds.printSchema();
```

but the compiler say:

```
Error:(23, 27) java: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

### Edited(Solution):

solution based on @Leet-Falcon answers:

```
DataFrame df = ctx.read().json(logFile);
Encoder<Person> encoder = Encoders.bean(Person.class);
Dataset<Person> ds = new Dataset<Person>(ctx, df.logicalPlan(), encoder);
```

Comment: Seems like the API is missing for Java /w Spark 1.6

Comment: how can I write the missing api in Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Official Spark docs suggest in [Dataset API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) the following:

> Java Encoders are specified by calling static methods on ***[Encoders](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#method_summary)***.

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("abc", "abc", "xyz");
Dataset<String> ds = context.createDataset(data, Encoders.STRING());
```

Encoders can be composed into tuples:

```
Encoder<Tuple2<Integer, String>> encoder2 = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.INT(), Encoders.STRING());
List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> data2 = Arrays.asList(new scala.Tuple2(1, "a");
Dataset<Tuple2<Integer, String>> ds2 = context.createDataset(data2, encoder2);
```

Or constructed from Java Beans by [Encoders#bean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#bean(java.lang.Class)):

```
Encoders.bean(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Is there a performance implication when transforming a DataFrame to a Dataset? Specifically, what happens when I attach an Encoder to a DataFrame? Is the encoder 'lazy' (i.e. it does nothing unless a typed operation is invoked) or does it have to process the DataFrame first?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to convert a generic DF to a Dataset in Java, you can use RowEncoder class like below

```
DataFrame df = sql.read().json(sc.parallelize(ImmutableList.of(
            "{\"id\": 0, \"phoneNumber\": 109, \"zip\": \"94102\"}"
    )));

    Dataset<Row> dataset = df.as(RowEncoder$.MODULE$.apply(df.schema()));
```

Comment: Like this in scala 
```val encoder = Encoders.product[Foo]

df.as[Foo](encoder)```

Comment: Problem is DataFrame class is gone from Spark 2!

Comment: Its not working as is.
 
Dataset<Row> dataset = df.as(RowEncoder$.MODULE$.apply(df.schema()));
getting an error " incompatible type".