# How to convert RDD of custom Java class objects to a DataFrame with toDF()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a Spark RDD to a Spark SQL dataframe with `toDF()`. I have used this function successfully many times, but in this case I'm getting a compiler error:

```
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.example.protobuf.SensorData]
```

Here is my code below:

```
// SensorData is an auto-generated class
import com.example.protobuf.SensorData
def loadSensorDataToRdd : RDD[SensorData] = ???

object MyApplication {
  def main(argv: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("My application")
    conf.set("io.compression.codecs", "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val sensorDataRdd = loadSensorDataToRdd()
    val sensorDataDf = sensorDataRdd.toDF() // <-- CAUSES COMPILER ERROR
  }
}
```

I am guessing that the problem is with the SensorData class, which is a Java class that was auto-generated from a [Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial). What can I do in order to convert the RDD to a dataframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark#31276515

Comment: Where is `tripSummary` created?

Comment: @Zzrot: Sorry, that was a typo. This line causes a compiler error: `sensorDataRdd().toDF()`.

Comment: `.toDF()` expects `sensorDataRdd` to be of the datatype `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Row]` and not `SensorData`.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40625586/6576230 might help. :)

Comment: @Zzrot: I read the link to the other Stackoverflow question. I don't understand what I should try next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the compilation error is that there's no `Encoder` in scope to convert a `RDD` with `com.example.protobuf.SensorData` to a `Dataset` of `com.example.protobuf.SensorData`.

`Encoders` (`ExpressionEncoders` to be exact) are used to convert `InternalRow` objects into JVM objects according to the schema (usually a case class or a Java bean).

There's a hope you can create an `Encoder` for the custom Java class using `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders` object's `bean` method.

> Creates an encoder for Java Bean of type T.

Something like the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
implicit val SensorDataEncoder = Encoders.bean(classOf[com.example.protobuf.SensorData])
```

If `SensorData` uses unsupported types you'll have to `map` the `RDD[SensorData]` to an `RDD` of some simpler type(s), e.g. a tuple of the fields, and only then expect `toDF` work.

Comment: +1 Converting a custom object RDD to Dataset<Row> (aka DataFrame) is not the right answer, but going to Dataset<SensorData> via an encoder IS the right answer. Datasets with custom objects are ideal because you'll get compilation errors and catalyst optimizer performance gains.

Comment: Sure! Wouldn't have said it better @Garren, but that was outside this question and hence didn't even bother mentioning it. Good point, though! Thanks. I might add your comment if I see the comment's upvotes (yours or mine) ;-)

Comment: The question was about converting a custom object RDD to a Dataframe which would be a silly conversion, so I felt clarifying your intent to use a Dataset<SensorData> instead of the specific DataFrame request was tangentially within the scope of the question

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Please do add any additional information that could help me (and others).

Comment: @Garren: I am relatively new to Spark and have been using either RDDs or DataFrames. I am not familiar with DataSets at all, but I was under the impression that a DataFrame is simply an alias for a DataSet (see this page: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-dataframe.html). Is there a more substantial difference between DataFrame and a DataSet that would help my understanding to solve this problem?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 DataFrame is indeed an alias specifically for `Dataset<Row>` - Row is a _generic row object_ NOT a custom class object (such as SensorData). That excellent book you cited is written by the very guy who answered your question ;). 

I can't find the image I want showing the RDD/DF/DS run/compile time breakdowns, but runner up: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3rF6p.png

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424854/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-dataset-and-rdd
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654145/how-to-convert-dataframe-to-dataset-in-apache-spark-in-java