# Spark reads Parquet file, and returns POJO objects, instead of Dataset<Row>

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Suppose I have a POJO class named `User`, and below is what I'm doing to put a list of User objects into a parquet file,

```
List<User> users = ...;
Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(users, User.class);
df.write().parquet("...");
```

I can then simply read it via,

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().parquet("...");
```

But what if I want spark to read it out as POJO objects, something like `RDD<User>`, is it possible?

Most of the examples found on google is using Avro-support-for-parquet, but I don't use Avro here.

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

(I'm using Spark 2.4)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654145/how-to-convert-dataframe-to-dataset-in-apache-spark-in-java) might help

Comment: You can just read a Dataset using `spark.read.parquet(...).as[User]`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html